# How to calculate 2 level page table size?

Tags: memory, memory-management, computer-science, virtual-memory

Given : 
32 bit virtual address, 
4KiB per page, 
4B - size of page table entrie, 
1 - GiB size of address space

For a process is using 1GiB address space, find out size of 1-level page table and 2-levels page table, when page table directory has got 1024 entries.
For 2-level page table - What is max and min size of page table?

So... I know that page offset is 12 bits and page number is 20 bits. So we got 2^20 entries, so total page table size should be 4.2 MB for 1-level page table.

But how can I calculate size of 2-levels page table? any tips?

Comment: Actually, there is no answer to this question under the parameters given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two level case may be examined thus:

1. There will be one page at level one.
2. There will be enough pages for the required address space at level two.

Now each level 2 page can map 2^10 * 2^12 bytes since it has 2^10 entries and each of those points to a page of 2^12 bytes. This yields 2^22 bytes.

Now your target address space is 2^30 (1GB) so you need 2^30/2^22 or 2^8 level 2 pages. In addition, you need one level one page.

The total used is 1 + 2^8 or 257 pages or 1028 KB

Comment: Okey, so the maximum is 1GB and the page table look like 2^8 level 2 pages, each of them got 2^10 entries and each of entires is 4KiB so the size is 2^8 * 2^10 * 4KiB = 1GB. But what about the minimum? Is it 4MB? We got 1 level 2 page, so the size is just 2*10 * 4KiB = 4MB?

Comment: wait... is 1GB size of the table page? And then maximum is 2^10 * 2^10 * 4KiB and the minimum is 2^10 * 4KiB?

Comment: No, the page table is just a bit more than 1 Meg

Comment: The smallest address space is 4 K, the size of one page. In a two level system this would need one level one page and one level two page. Remember that the page tables are not required to be full. They are allowed to have only one entry.